# Javascript .removeChild not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dom

I feel like I am misunderstanding how `.removeChild` works. I have some code here:

```
//organization is a string value gotten from an Input node

if (organization == '') {
    //there is nothing in the organization form
    if (orgContainer !== undefined) {
        console.log(orgContainer + ' exists and there is nothing in the organization form.');
        //remove the orgContainer
        orgContainer.parentNode.removeChild(orgContainer);
        console.log(orgContainer + 'removed!');
    } else {
        console.log(orgContainer + ' does not exist and there is nothing in the organization form.')
    }
} else {
    if (orgContainer !== undefined || orgContainer !== null) {
        console.log(orgContainer + ' exists and there is something in the organization form.');
    } else {
        console.log(orgContainer + ' does not exist and there is something in the organization form.')
    }
}
```

Basically when I check my page after calling `orgContainer.parentNode.removeChild(orgContainer)` I get the console log message of `orgContainer removed!` BUT when I run the function again it says that `orgContainer` still exists even though I removed it with `.removeChild`?

Am I misunderstanding how `.removeChild` works? My node gets removed from the parent node but does it not actually cease to exist or something? Does it just get deleted from the DOM but not from memory or something?

I get this wonderful console.log message `undefined exists and there is something in the organization form.` .. What? How does it exist if it's `undefined`? I've read through the documentation on the developer.mozilla.org site but I am still a bit confused. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript variable still has a reference to the node, and nothing in your code attempts to change that. You successfully take the node out of the DOM, but the value of the `orgContainer` variable is never changed.

Comment: Ooh I see. I just need to remove the reference from `orgContainer`? Can I just set it to null or something? Is there a better way to remove the reference?

Comment: @shanling yes, set it to `null` or `undefined` or something. The DOM is just a big data structure; the only thing special about it is that the objects are not purely JavaScript objects, but (mostly) they behave as if they were.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove a declared variable. Although it has been removed from DOM, it doesn't mean it will "undeclare" your variable. You can manually set it to `undefined` if you want.

```
orgContainer = undefined;
```